# How to set fast the same customizations that i had in the previus versions of Blender?

Tags: customization

I have installed the new version of Blender 2.83, is very cool but now i have lost all customizations that i had in the 2.80 version. For exemple "Quick Favorites" or the layout. So there is a fast way to import/export all  customizations that i had in the previeus versions?

Answer (score 1):

Just copy the preferences files to the new version. 
Look for the ***userpref.blend*** of the old version and copy it to the folder of the new one.

In Linux is usually in /home/*yourusername*/.config/blender/*version number*/config.

For Windows it should be in \users\ *your user name*\AppData\Roaming\Blender Foundation\Blender\ *version number* \config.